# Different results with Shapiro Wilk test in R

Tags: r, statistics, static-analysis

I have a large data for an independent sample t-test with two factors, one of them is Gender. I want it to check the normality of each group in variable to decide the next step. So I took the following script that I found in this forum with some modifications.

```
for (i in 9:ncol(AF)) {
  print(names(AF)[i]) 
  print(AF %>%
          group_by(Gender) %>%
          summarise(`W Statistic` = ifelse(sd(AF[, i])!=0,
                                           shapiro.test(AF[, i])$statistic,NA),
                    `p-value` = ifelse(sd(AF[, i])!=0,
                                       shapiro.test(AF[, i])$p.value,NA)))
}
```

The result for the first variables (R_44) was a follows:

```
## [1] "R_44"
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   Gender Statistic `p-value`
##   <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 F          0.560  9.31e-10
## 2 M          0.560  9.31e-10
```

This variable at the beginning of my work I remembered doing its normality check using JASP and it was different.

In JASP the result was different:

```
## 1 F          0.465  1.559e -7
## 2 M          0.623  5.149e -6
```

I repeated the test in R for the same variable without the loop function as below:

```
shapiro.test(AF$R_44[AF$Gender == "F"])
shapiro.test(AF$R_44[AF$Gender == "M"])
```

The results were:

```
data:  AF$R_44[AF$Gender == "F"]
W = 0.46505, p-value = 1.559e-07

data:  AF$R_44[AF$Gender == "M"]
W = 0.62303, p-value = 5.149e-06
```

similar to JASP. Therefore, I assume I have a mistake in the first script above but I am not sure where is it. Need help here!

Answer (score 1):

`AF[, i]` is subsetting data from the entire dataframe and does not take into consideration the grouping by `Gender`. You may use `cur_data()` to subset data from the current group.

Also since `sd` returns a single value it is better to use `if`/`else` instead of vectorised `ifelse`.

Something like this should work, I can't test this since I don't have the data.

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in 9:ncol(AF)) {
  print(names(AF)[i]) 
  print(AF %>%
          group_by(Gender) %>%
          summarise(`W Statistic` = if(sd(select(cur_data(), i)) !=0)
                            shapiro.test(cur_data()[[i]])$statistic else NA
                    `p-value` = if(sd(select(cur_data(), i)) !=0)
                            shapiro.test(cur_data()[[i]])$p.value else NA)
}
```